# TypeScript strictly typed keys in a partial object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using [Mui](https://material-ui.com) components with TypeScript and trying to build a helper function to generate extended variants.

```
import { ButtonProps, ButtonPropsSizeOverrides } from "@mui/material";

declare module "@mui/material/Button" {

  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
    light: true;
  }

}

type ButtonVariant = ButtonProps["variant"];

const buttonVariants: readonly Exclude<ButtonVariant, undefined>[] = [
  "contained",
  "outlined",
  "light",
  "text",
] as const;
```

I have actually had this working for a while using a `key: string` value for the object it returns:

```
const makeVariants = (): { [key: string]: () => void } => {
  return {
    light: () => {},
  };
};
```

But I found a typo in one place, and that made me realize I should make this type-safe — instead of `string` (effectively any string as a key), I should require that the key be a member of the `buttonVariants`.

I naively tried this:

```
type VariantMakerKey = typeof buttonVariants[number];

const makeVariants = (): { [key in VariantMakerKey]: () => void } => {
  return {
    light: () => {},
  };
};
```

But TypeScript is mad because I didn't return all the properties.

```
// Type '{ light: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 
// '{ text: () => void; 
//    outlined: () => void; 
//    contained: () => void; 
//    light: () => void; }': text, outlined, contained
```

How can I make the object that returns only require a partial set of keys, so that *if* I define a key, it **must** be in `buttonVariants`, but I'm not required to declare them all?

Comment: Do you want to make the properties optional: https://tsplay.dev/WJ7Olw?

Comment: RIDICULOUS, thank you @TobiasS! Feel free to toss that in as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapped type constructs an object type containing *all* the members of `buttonVariants`. We have to find a way to make them *optional* to stop the compiler from requiring *all* properties to be set.

Their are certain [*Mapping Modifiers*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) which can change the result of a mapped type. The `?` modifier makes all properties optional.

```
const makeVariants = (): { [key in VariantMakerKey]?: () => void } => {
  return {
    light: () => {},
  };
};
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQK4xhAdgBShMAZwBoV1Nd8iBlYALwFMB5ANwaimABMHC4BfOADN8IOACIAAiFTAA9CACGMdsEUAbcQG4AUDp4BjdYqgM4ICF1TqzUmfKUrOGuWgzZxiPXDjAsToUUDMzcKPAJCADUTNX9Wdk4ePgQdHx91YABzAAsYAC44GChUBl0ffj0KnRgATzAQ8mxo5384AF4yd0oIgG1xFhjFf3EAXV0dA2xCeAAjRqxm2JhCAtNFLmx1GrgAUQAPI1QeAB5QpsH-UlQsHiE-Bi4APh6R9rge1IlJ-0V7rnFiJ9xBB0BksA8AUCMjkYJCfOIVHtYYDXoo+N9puNavU4IshjAALKKADW7AA0gxth1sQwIEI4HMunj-IQelhUCAZuwxnoMfAlKTmcs3gAKACUBSQPVJ2z8uIuhJJ5MpIwA-AVxe1HnAWBBuAItV4fKYYKgoFgjWlobkNWLDQh+IDyrp+FogA)